# How to remove the query string from 404 Not Found errors in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have set up a custom `404 Not Found` error page using the httpErrors section in my `Web.config` file.

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="404"/>
  <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/error/notfound"/>
</httpErrors>
```

When I navigate to a non-existent page, I get the following URL:

> http://localhost/error/notfound?404;http://localhost/ThisPageDoesNotExist/

I don't want the query string in the URL and I don't want to 301 or 302 redirect to the notfound page either. How can I achieve this? Using URL rewriting perhaps?

Comment: Try changing the responseMode to `Redirect` instead of ExecuteURL.

Comment: That causes a redirect. I prefer a rewrite which ExecuteURL does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to handle **404** Not Found errors handled without re-writing the url and by simply returning a result view

One way to achieve this is to use the old `customErrors` but with `redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"` to ensure that the original url is not changed.

```
   <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/NotFound" />
  </customErrors>
```

The other is to use the `httpErrors` method with `existingResponse="Replace"` **Exactly the way you are currenly using it**

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <clear/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="/Errors/NotFound.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
```

---

I have tried to recreate your issue and only succeeded when I had both `httpErrors` and `customErrors` set **without** `redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"`

**My Conclusion:** you are probably using `customErrors` without `ResponseRewrite` which takes precedence over `httpErrors` handler.

Answer (score -1):

If you supply your own querystring when specifying the path, then .NET will NOT tack on the `aspxerrorpath`.

For example:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="errorpage.aspx?error=1" >
```

You could also create a `HttpHandler` which catches URLs with `aspxerrorpath` in it, and strips it. You could probably do the same with the rewrite module in IIS7 as well.

Or, in the `global.asax`, catch the 404 error and redirect to the file not found page. Example:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
    if (ex is HttpException && ((HttpException)ex).GetHttpCode() == 404)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/filenotfound.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        // your global error handling here!
    }
}
```

Comment: That's still pretty ugly.